# Retrieving information from a web page in Python?

Tags: python

I have the following page:

http://www.noncode.org/keyword.php

from where I want to extract some information from it by performing an external search by Python. Maybe it will sound simple, but I have not programmed web applications before.

So I would like to put in the search box something like:

NONHSAT146018.2

[image]

to perform a search and from the resulting webpage, which is this:

[image]

From the results I need to extract the field that it says Sequence. I have read some information about the Beautiful Soup library and some examples, but they do not include in the address the PHP form.

Update: Following the advice of the users and with the help of @Lukas Newman, I made the following:

```
data="NONHSAT146018.2"
page = requests.get("http://www.noncode.org/show_rna.php?id=" + data)
soup=BS(page.content,'html.parser')
target = soup.find('h2',text='Sequence')
print(target)
   
target = soup.find('table',text='table-1')
print(target)

table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class'},text='table-1')
print(table)
```

When I inspect the results I got that the sequence is in the following field:

[image]

How can I extract that part by using Python?

Comment: Please, spend some time reading ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results by following the tips in those articles.

Comment: thanks @accdias, but the example was just to retrieve the information from this page. The code I made with BS was not retrieving any data.

Comment: Even though it is not working, it is good practice around here to show us what you have tried.

Comment: thank you for your advice @accdias, I will keep in mind for future posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the url

```
http://www.noncode.org/show_rna.php?id=NONHSAT000002
```

The search is just passed as a get parameter. So to access the side just set the start url to something like:

```
import requests
from bs4 import *

id = "NONHSAT146018"
page = requests.get("http://www.noncode.org/show_rna.php?id=" + id)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

element = soup.findAll('table', class_="table-1")[1]
element2 = element.findAll('tr')[1]
element3 = element2.findNext('td')
your_data = str(element3.renderContents(), "utf-8")
print(your_data)
```

Comment: thanks @LukasNeumann, I got a 200 response which I believe that the page has downloaded, but how to obtain the specific Sequence part? Could you give me a hand?

Comment: @Little Sure, I would recommend to have a look at this: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-tutorial-python/ Basically, the next thing you need to do is to get the html of the page with "page.content" and then parse it with beautiful soup to find your sequence. If you need more help, feel free to ask me.

Comment: thanks @Lukas Neumann very kind from your side, I will try to code this and will send you a reply if I get stucked. Thank you.

Comment: I have tried to retrieve the sequence, but no luck at all. I see that in the dump of the webpage it does not appear, but I read that this could be because the data is dynamically created. Could you help me to extract that sequence of dna?

Comment: @Little I put the whole soulution in my awnser, basically  it takes the second element thats in the class "table-1" then the second "tr" and then the "td". Last of all it gets the text and converts it to utf-8. You can "follow" this path when you inspect the site in the browser. I hoped I helped you, if you have more question, feel free to ask more!

Comment: thank you @Lukas Neumann, it retrieves a sequence, but I found that the one that I am looking starts with "ttgtt...", but strangely this start with "AACTTGCCGTCAGC", maybe is there other sequence hid in the html? what could be happening?

Comment: @Little I just put in a other id ;-) , its fixed now! To change the id, just change the variable "id"